# compare two text files and output the difference + the name of the file the record was found in

Tags: python, csv, text, difference

Hello I wrote a script that compares two text files and outputs the difference into a separate text file (difference.txt). My goal is to have the name of the file the records were taken from either at the beginning of each row or end of each row before moving onto the next row in my difference.txt.

My script is fairly straightforward:

```
Jan = "JanFile.txt"
Feb = "FebFile.txt"
rootFolder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

with open (Jan, "rt") as doc1, open(Feb, "rt") as doc2:
    prevMonth = set(doc1.readlines())
    currentMonth = set(doc2.readlines())

with open ('TxtDiff.txt', 'wt') as unmatchedFile:
    line = (currentMonth - prevMonth)
    unmatchedFile.writelines(line)
```

Just to reiterate: I would like to know which file the records came from in the difference.txt file. Is there anyway to append this information so it appears either before or after the row

Ex:

**JanFile would look like:**

```
Column1 | Column2
Data1   | Data2
```

**FebFile would look like:**

```
Column1 | Column2
Data1   | Data2
```

**Difference.txt would look like:**

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3
JanFile | Data1   | Data2
FebFile | Data1   | Data2
FebFile | Data1   | Data2
JanFile | Data1   | Data2
```

I am pretty adamant about using the 
line = (currentMonth - prevMonth) as using diff, pandas, xlrd, etc has created many other problems.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: welcome! To make you code run, your filenames need leading quotes.

Comment: Add a field of filename in your readlines list of each file.

Comment: `a=['col1,col2,col3','col1,col2,col3']
a=['file1,'+i for i in a]`

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. Could you please elaborate a little more?
Thank you!

Comment: You are missing a quote character: `Jan = JanFile.txt"` should be `Jan = "JanFile.txt"`. You can use the [edit] button to make improvements to your question. It would help if you gave a better example as with what you have, it is difficult to see the logic needed.

Comment: Yes, I realized that after I made the post. It was just a typo and has been fixed now. Anyway, I'm not sure how much more information I need to give in order for it to be a better example. I feel I was pretty straightforward with what my output needs to be

Comment: I just need to know which files (either Jan, or Feb in this came) the TxtDiff.txt records came from

Comment: In your example the `Jan` and `Feb` files look identical, i.e. no differences. But your `Difference.txt` shows 4 lines of output. Please explain the steps needed to create this output.